# How to build latest version of Spark for a MapR version?

Tags: apache-spark, mapr

I am running an old MapR cluster, mapr3.

How can I build a custom distribution for Spark 1.5.x for mapr3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is getting the right hadoop.version is the key step to make everything work.

I went back to version **spark 1.3.1** and found the mapr3 profile in which it had `hadoop.version=1.0.3-mapr-3.0.3`.  To build a complete distribution, the following command will work if you have JAVA_HOME set already:

```
./make-distribution.sh --name custom-spark --tgz -Dhadoop.version=1.0.3-mapr-3.0.3 -Phadoop-1 -DskipTests
```